# Blender + Animations to Unreal Engine 4

Tags: export, .fbx, unreal-engine

This might seem completely nooby to a lot of people but I just seem to be unable to do this.

I created a small Animation containing 2 planes and 6 Curves Resulting in:
[image]

Now I am attempting to Export this as fbx and import in the Unreal Engine 4.23 and to use. But it seems that only a part is exported.

After Import 5 Parts appear in Unreal Engine 4. 1 Mesh, 2 Animations, 1 Physics, and 1 Skeletol Mesh.

But After taking a look at the Animation:
[image]

But the Only that seems to be exported is one of the circles and the rest has dissappeared as well that the animations are not playing.

I selected every part in blender executed Ctrl + A and Scale. Then Exported as .fbx, Sleceted Mesh and Armature.

Does Anyone have an Idea what I am doing Wrong?

(ADD Part)

I do not know if this helps. I attempted to just export the first ring as fbx an import to Unreal. Again the same result the mesh appears but the animation is lost, but even though:
[image]
So it tells me that the import has an animation of 24 fps and 40 frames long? So it was exported correctly I assume, but importing the circle again to Blender, in that case the is animation is also not present!! What is going on?? I am lost on this.

Comment: Small Update, It seems that the Animations have not been exported at all, as importing the fbx back to blender is unable to find any animations.

Comment: Transform your path into keyframes animation